# Database is not being created, with different tried approaches in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

The problem I am facing in SQLite Database creation is that I do not see any DATABASE_NAME.db file being created in the DDMS perspective, when using an AVD. While I have a conviction that the code I am using is correct ,since it is  from an online tutorial. Leaving only 1 flaw, which is pointed out below, I suppose:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class AABDatabaseManager {

    private SQLiteDatabase db; // a reference to the database manager class.
    private final String DB_NAME = "database_name"; // the name of our database
    private final int DB_VERSION = 1; // the version of the database

    // the names for our database columns
    private final String TABLE_NAME = "database_table";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_ID = "id";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_ONE = "table_row_one";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_TWO = "table_row_two";

    // TODO: write the constructor and methods for this class

    // the beginnings our SQLiteOpenHelper class
    private class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        // TODO: override the constructor and other methods for the parent class

        //super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION); I had to comment out this //statement because it gave me error-->>Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block


        public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            // the SQLite query string that will create our 3 column database table.
            String newTableQueryString =    
                "create table " +
                TABLE_NAME +
                " (" +
                TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text," +
                TABLE_ROW_TWO + " text" +
                ");";

            // execute the query string to the database.
            db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // NOTHING TO DO HERE. THIS IS THE ORIGINAL DATABASE VERSION.
            // OTHERWISE, YOU WOULD SPECIFIY HOW TO UPGRADE THE DATABASE
            // FROM OLDER VERSIONS.
        }
    }

    public void addRow(String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo)
    {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        // this is how you add a value to a ContentValues object
        // we are passing in a key string and a value string each time
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowStringTwo);

        // ask the database object to insert the new data 
        try
        {
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString()); // prints the error message to the log
            e.printStackTrace(); // prints the stack trace to the log
        }
    }

    public void deleteRow(long rowID)
    {
        // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
        try
        {
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateRow(long rowID, String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo)
    {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowStringTwo);

        // ask the database object to update the database row of given rowID
        try {db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Additional Code */

    /**********************************************************************
     * RETRIEVING ALL ROWS FROM THE DATABASE TABLE
     * 
     * This is an example of how to retrieve all data from a database
     * table using this class.  You should edit this method to suit your
     * needs.
     * 
     * the key is automatically assigned by the database
     */
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllRowsAsArrays()
    {
        // create an ArrayList that will hold all of the data collected from
        // the database.
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays =
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
        // the cursor object store the information collected from the
        // database and is used to iterate through the data.
        Cursor cursor;

        try
        {
            // ask the database object to create the cursor.
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO},
                    null, null, null, null, null
            );

            // move the cursor's pointer to position zero.
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data after the current cursor position, add it
            // to the ArrayList.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                do
                {
                    ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));

                    dataArrays.add(dataList);
                }
                // move the cursor's pointer up one position.
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the ArrayList that holds the data collected from
        // the database.
        return dataArrays;
    }




    /**********************************************************************
     * RETRIEVING A ROW FROM THE DATABASE TABLE
     * 
     * This is an example of how to retrieve a row from a database table
     * using this class.  You should edit this method to suit your needs.
     * 
     * @param rowID the id of the row to retrieve
     * @return an array containing the data from the row
     */
    public ArrayList<Object> getRowAsArray(long rowID)
    {
        // create an array list to store data from the database row.
        // I would recommend creating a JavaBean compliant object 
        // to store this data instead.  That way you can ensure
        // data types are correct.
        ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Cursor cursor;

        try
        {
            // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
            // the cursor object store the information collected from the
            // database and is used to iterate through the data.
            cursor = db.query
            (
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO },
                    TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,
                    null, null, null, null, null
            );

            // move the pointer to position zero in the cursor.
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data available after the cursor's pointer, add
            // it to the ArrayList that will be returned by the method.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                do
                {
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // let java know that you are through with the cursor.
            cursor.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the ArrayList containing the given row from the database.
        return rowArray;
    }



}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! I hope it is not some issue related to IDE

The Logcat output is::

```
07-09 10:13:24.205: E/ERROR(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:13:24.205: W/System.err(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:13:24.215: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.AABDatabaseManager.getAllRowsAsArrays(AABDatabaseManager.java:144)
07-09 10:13:24.215: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.updateTable(MainActivity.java:290)
07-09 10:13:24.225: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
07-09 10:13:24.225: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-09 10:13:24.235: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-09 10:13:24.235: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-09 10:13:24.267: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-09 10:13:24.267: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-09 10:13:24.285: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-09 10:13:24.285: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 10:13:24.295: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 10:13:24.304: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 10:13:24.304: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:13:24.304: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 10:13:24.314: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 10:13:24.314: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 10:13:24.325: W/System.err(985):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:13:24.695: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:13:26.656: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:13:27.144: D/gralloc_goldfish(985): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-09 10:13:48.964: D/dalvikvm(985): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 145K, 9% free 2874K/3136K, paused 174ms, total 188ms
07-09 10:13:52.204: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:13:54.064: E/DB ERROR(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:13:54.074: W/System.err(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:13:54.134: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.AABDatabaseManager.addRow(AABDatabaseManager.java:79)
07-09 10:13:54.134: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.addRow(MainActivity.java:150)
07-09 10:13:54.154: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:145)
07-09 10:13:54.154: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
07-09 10:13:54.165: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-09 10:13:54.165: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-09 10:13:54.184: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-09 10:13:54.184: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 10:13:54.194: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 10:13:54.194: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 10:13:54.204: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:13:54.204: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 10:13:54.214: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 10:13:54.214: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 10:13:54.224: W/System.err(985):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:13:54.224: E/Add Error(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:13:54.234: W/System.err(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:13:54.244: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.AABDatabaseManager.getAllRowsAsArrays(AABDatabaseManager.java:144)
07-09 10:13:54.255: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.updateTable(MainActivity.java:290)
07-09 10:13:54.274: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.addRow(MainActivity.java:157)
07-09 10:13:54.274: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:145)
07-09 10:13:54.284: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
07-09 10:13:54.294: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-09 10:13:54.294: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-09 10:13:54.304: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-09 10:13:54.316: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 10:13:54.316: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 10:13:54.324: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 10:13:54.334: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:13:54.344: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 10:13:54.344: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 10:13:54.354: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 10:13:54.364: W/System.err(985):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:14:02.895: E/SpannableStringBuilder(985): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-09 10:14:02.895: E/SpannableStringBuilder(985): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-09 10:14:05.855: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:14:06.625: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:14:07.585: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:14:09.525: E/DB ERROR(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:14:09.525: W/System.err(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:14:09.555: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.AABDatabaseManager.addRow(AABDatabaseManager.java:79)
07-09 10:14:09.555: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.addRow(MainActivity.java:150)
07-09 10:14:09.625: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:145)
07-09 10:14:09.635: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
07-09 10:14:09.656: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-09 10:14:09.656: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-09 10:14:09.665: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-09 10:14:09.665: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 10:14:09.665: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 10:14:09.695: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 10:14:09.695: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:14:09.715: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 10:14:09.715: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 10:14:09.745: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 10:14:09.745: W/System.err(985):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:14:09.756: E/Add Error(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:14:09.756: W/System.err(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:14:09.785: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.AABDatabaseManager.getAllRowsAsArrays(AABDatabaseManager.java:144)
07-09 10:14:09.785: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.updateTable(MainActivity.java:290)
07-09 10:14:09.806: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.addRow(MainActivity.java:157)
07-09 10:14:09.835: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:145)
07-09 10:14:09.835: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
07-09 10:14:09.835: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-09 10:14:09.865: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-09 10:14:09.875: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-09 10:14:09.885: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 10:14:09.895: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 10:14:09.895: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 10:14:09.905: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:14:09.905: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 10:14:09.915: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 10:14:09.925: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 10:14:09.925: W/System.err(985):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:14:19.634: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:14:19.734: E/SpannableStringBuilder(985): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-09 10:14:19.734: E/SpannableStringBuilder(985): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-09 10:14:21.805: E/DB ERROR(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:14:21.805: W/System.err(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:14:21.924: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.AABDatabaseManager.addRow(AABDatabaseManager.java:79)
07-09 10:14:21.944: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.addRow(MainActivity.java:150)
07-09 10:14:21.944: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:145)
07-09 10:14:21.944: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
07-09 10:14:21.954: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-09 10:14:21.954: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-09 10:14:21.964: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-09 10:14:21.974: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 10:14:21.974: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 10:14:21.984: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 10:14:21.984: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:14:21.994: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 10:14:22.004: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 10:14:22.004: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 10:14:22.014: W/System.err(985):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:14:22.014: E/Add Error(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:14:22.024: W/System.err(985): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:14:22.058: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.AABDatabaseManager.getAllRowsAsArrays(AABDatabaseManager.java:144)
07-09 10:14:22.058: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.updateTable(MainActivity.java:290)
07-09 10:14:22.064: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.addRow(MainActivity.java:157)
07-09 10:14:22.064: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:145)
07-09 10:14:22.075: W/System.err(985):  at com.example.haloapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
07-09 10:14:22.075: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-09 10:14:22.084: W/System.err(985):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-09 10:14:22.084: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-09 10:14:22.094: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 10:14:22.104: W/System.err(985):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 10:14:22.138: W/System.err(985):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 10:14:22.138: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:14:22.138: W/System.err(985):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 10:14:22.144: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 10:14:22.144: W/System.err(985):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 10:14:22.144: W/System.err(985):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:15:09.164: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:21:41.265: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:21:42.525: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 10:21:42.775: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(985): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-09 10:21:48.015: I/Choreographer(985): Skipped 131 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: are you getting any exception? if yes post them here. if not then the database would be getting created. are you able to perform any operations on database once running the code to create it? if not then post the logcat here.

Comment: I think you have commented a super called where the DB was created.

Comment: I don't get any exception. The app has buttons to add to the database, which seem like being non reactive at all. Here's also my LogCat. And Alfaplus- I had to comment it out because of the Syntax error it gave. It told to close the class with "}"

Answer (score 1):

add .db extension to this line

```
private final String DB_NAME = "database_name"; // the name of our database
```

so it looks like this

```
private final String DB_NAME = "database_name.db"; // the name of our database
```

EDIT - everytime you reference db it is null, you need to get a reference to the database like so:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
// OR
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
// depending on what type of action you need to perform (READ vs WRITE)
```

Comment: Tried this, but this doesn't seem to be a solution. Please also refer to the LogCat

Comment: This will allow you to access the database in DDMS but it will not fix an issue in the database. Also I don't see your logcat

Comment: Please refresh this web page

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to create a database, if you comment this super called, no database is going to be created.

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }
```

More or less this is the code that i am using and works perfectly.

Code:

```
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_name = "name";
    public static final String KEY_nr = "nr";

    private static DBAdapter instance;

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SecretDatabaseHelper secretDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb, secretDB;
    private android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase questionDB;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String IN_TABLE = "in_table";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String IN_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
            + IN_TABLE + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_name + " text, " + KEY_nr + " text"
            + ");";
    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(IN_TABLE_CREATE);        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }

    private DBAdapter(Context ctx) {

        mCtx = ctx;

    }

    public static synchronized DBAdapter getInstance(Context ctx) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBAdapter(ctx);
            SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(ctx);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public DBAdapter open(String password) throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(password);

        return this;
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        if (mDb != null) {
            return mDb.isOpen();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }   public Cursor getInCursor() {
        return mDb.query(IN_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }


}
```

Comment: Ya, but for that haven't I got this in the following line: public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
    CursorFactory factory, int version) {
   super(context, name, factory, version);
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

Comment: UPDATE: Also tried after adding this super call, but not to fruition

Answer (score 0):

This is my DataBaseHandler class. You can modify it for your Use.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_MEMBER_ID = "memberid";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MEMBER_ID + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_MOBILE + " TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD
            + " TEXT," + KEY_UID + " TEXT," + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT"
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String name, String memberid, String email,
        String address, String mobile, String password, String uid,
        String created_at) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_MEMBER_ID, memberid);// Member ID
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);// Address
    values.put(KEY_MOBILE, mobile);// Mobile
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);// Password
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {

    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
        user.put("memberid",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MEMBER_ID)));
        user.put("email",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
        user.put("address",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS)));
        user.put("mobile",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOBILE)));
        user.put("password",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD)));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_UID)));
        user.put("created_at",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Getting user login status return true if rows are there in table
 * */
public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    // return row count
    return rowCount;
}

/**
 * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void resetTables() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
    db.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();`

Include this line every time whenever inserting updating the database
you need database reference every time as it is `null`